# how best to send the output of a find + exec command to a pipeline?

Tags: find, pipe, exec

I would like to understand how to correctly send the output of a find + exec command to a pipeline for further processing.

i.e. how can we
(1) select a group files
(2) perform some operation on the group via exec and
(3) use the output of that operation as input to 1 or more filters in a pipeline

For example, when I try to filter a find + exec command like so, I see lots of 'terminated by signal 13' errors for the lines that I filtered out.

```
$ find c* -name "*.jpg" -exec ls {} \; | head
c0/1467058201899.jpg
c0/1465854461118.jpg
c0/1465855196637.jpg
c0/1467050962421.jpg
c0/1465856476225.jpg
c0/1467050385287.jpg
c0/1465853696999.jpg
c0/1467144293032.jpg
c0/1467051637981.jpg
c0/1465841226352.jpg
find: `ls' terminated by signal 13
find: `ls' terminated by signal 13
find: `ls' terminated by signal 13
...
```

I can make this particular error go away like so, but this does not feel very elegant.

```
$ find c* -name "*.jpg" -exec ls {} \; -print 2>/dev/null | head
c0/1467058201899.jpg
c0/1467058201899.jpg
c0/1465854461118.jpg
c0/1465854461118.jpg
c0/1465855196637.jpg
c0/1465855196637.jpg
c0/1467050962421.jpg
c0/1467050962421.jpg
c0/1465856476225.jpg
c0/1465856476225.jpg
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this for the general case of find + exec where the command being executed may vary?

**UPDATE**
using xargs still seems generate output to stderr ...

```
$ find c* -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 ls | head
c0/1465425913832.jpg
c0/1465425968779.jpg
c0/1465426112741.jpg
c0/1465426116540.jpg
c0/1465426121623.jpg
c0/1465426127656.jpg
c0/1465426133584.jpg
c0/1465426140097.jpg
c0/1465426143185.jpg
c0/1465426156715.jpg
xargs: ls: terminated by signal 13
```

using find + exec terminating with + instead of ; also generates output to stderr ...

```
$ find c* -name "*.jpg" -exec ls {} \+ | head
c0/1465425913832.jpg
c0/1465425968779.jpg
c0/1465426112741.jpg
c0/1465426116540.jpg
c0/1465426121623.jpg
c0/1465426127656.jpg
c0/1465426133584.jpg
c0/1465426140097.jpg
c0/1465426143185.jpg
c0/1465426156715.jpg
find: `ls' terminated by signal 13
find: `ls' terminated by signal 13
```

though adding "-print 2>/dev/null" to this command results in a command that executes very quickly ...

```
$ find c* -name "*.jpg" -exec ls {} \+ -print 2>/dev/null | head
c0/1467058201899.jpg
c0/1465854461118.jpg
c0/1465855196637.jpg
c0/1467050962421.jpg
c0/1465856476225.jpg
c0/1467050385287.jpg
c0/1465853696999.jpg
c0/1467144293032.jpg
c0/1467051637981.jpg
c0/1465841226352.jpg
```

Comment: There are of course many other ways you can achieve the same thing, but your "not very elegant" solution works fine.  In general, when using "find" to pipe files to some command (other than 'ls'), I use 'xargs', e.g. "find /etc -type f -name '*.jpg' -mtime +30 | xargs rm". This is much more efficient than using the find command's "ls" option, which forks a process for each and every match.

Comment: @Lee-Man You should use `find -print0` and `xargs -0`. By default, these utilities print and split on newlines, which means if I can put a file in `/etc`, I could name it `/etc/simplefile\n/home/leeman/mission-critical-document`, and rm would get `/etc/simplefile` as one argument, and `/home/leeman/mission-critical-document` as another. This is because newlines are allowed in filenames, but NULs are not.

Comment: Or with modern `find`, no need for `xargs`: `find ... -exec ... {} +`

Comment: Why are you using `ls` at all?  If you just did a `-print` in the find rather than the more obscure and much less efficient `-exec ls {}` then find would know you had stopped listening and exit gracefully.

Comment: *Why* are you using `ls`? `find` will produce a list by itself...

Comment: @Kusalananda The question is "how best to send the output of a find + exec command to a pipeline?" Translation: how can we (1) select a group files (2) perform some operation on the group via exec and (3) use the output of that operation as input to additional filters. "ls" is one example of an operation that can be performed on the selected group of files via exec.

Answer (score 3):

The error is occurring because `find` doesn't know when to stop. If you run `find | head`, when head gets its ten lines and exits, the next time `find` tries to write a filename, it'll get a **SIGPIPE** (letting it know that the other end of the pipe is broken or closed), and find will gracefully exit.

But here, find isn't writing anything, `ls` is. `find` can see that its children are dying, and it can see why, but it doesn't know that the other end of the pipe is closed, and it doesn't know to stop spawning them.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say in your third paragraph. `find` definitely does not capture the output of commands that it executes for `-exec`, that output goes wherever it goes (here, to the pipe).