# How do I handle strange path characters when piping find output?

Tags: bash, find, pipe, escape-characters

I had a problem where I wanted to find the length of each path from a `find` command. My first attempt was to run something like this:

```
find . -exec sh -c "echo {} | wc -c" \;
```

[I got this idea from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307154/61624). (The command above is **not** my question, I'm just using it as an example and it's completely contrived. Also, I may need more than one pipe sometimes.)

But when I ran it, there were errors in the output, likely due to special characters in the output paths. Unfortunately, I don't have the knowledge to troubleshoot which paths caused the issue and the error messages weren't informative. Regardless...

[I later stumbled upon this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243098/101311):

> The `find` command executes the command directly. The command, including the filename argument, will not be processed by the shell or anything else that might modify the filename. It's very safe.

That seems very convenient. So convenient, in fact, that the `-exec sh -c ...` "cure" seems worse than the disease.

So my question is, what should I do when I *need* to pipe commands with `find` and my paths may have special characters? **Is there a generic solution to this problem** where I don't have to consider a bunch of caveats? I am using bash.

---

Note: This is a similar question: [how best to send the output of a find + exec command to a pipeline?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295505/how-best-to-send-the-output-of-a-find-exec-command-to-a-pipeline) The difference is, I'm not necessarily trying to pipe the output outside of `-exec`. i.e., if `find ... -exec ... foo {} | bar \;` is the way to go, that's perfectly fine by me. I'm just looking for a generic path of least resistance, the structure of the command isn't important to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the filename as an argument to the shell script:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$1" | wc -c' sh {} \;
```

or for multiple files per shell invocation:

```
find . -exec sh -c 'for x in "$@"; do printf "%s\n" "$x" | wc -c; done' sh {} +
```

---

Your command

```
find . -exec sh -c "echo {} | wc -c" \;
```

would insert the filename as-is on the shell command line. It'd only work for filenames that don't contain whitespace or characters that are special to the shell. E.g. something like a `Don't stop me now.mp3`, `this&that.txt` would cause problems. (The first would produce an unterminated quoted string, and the second would start `echo` in the background, and then try to run a command called `that.txt`.)

On the other hand, `sh -c ... sh {} \;` (or `... {} +` has `find` pass the filename(s) as a distinct argument(s) to the shell, where they'll then be available in the positional parameters and can be used without them getting mixed with the shell syntax. (`"$1"` for the first, `"$@"` for the whole list. Remember the quotes.)

For the case of checking the filename length, you could also get it with `"${#var}"` in the shell, except that it gives the length in *characters* as per the current locale, while `wc -c` counts *bytes*.

Comment: Maybe printf rather than echo, so you can handle paths starting with a dash, etc. (I know it's the contrived example from the question, but why not fix it too)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Can you explain why the first one works when paths have strange characters? Also, what do you mean by "multiple files per shell invocation"?

Comment: @DanielKaplan, see edit (I was just typing that). With `echo {} | wc`, the filename gets embedded in the _code_ the shell executes, while when passing it as an argument it's data separate from  the code.

Comment: I've never seen `sh -c ... sh {} \;` what does that second `sh` do? Does it mean "run `...` in the second `sh`?" The man page says the second "sh" is a `command_name` and changes `$0`, but I'm not sure what ramifications that would have, especially since you are not referring to `$0`.

Comment: @DanielKaplan, exactly, it's just something that goes to `$0`. It has to be there for the following args to go to to `$1`, `$2`, ... Only the ones from 1 up show in `$@`, and `$0` shows in some error messages.

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I thought but I wanted to confirm. re: "multiple files per shell invocation", I incorrectly assumed `+` was a synonym for `\;`, so TIL. Thanks. I guess one last thing: would you say your answer is preferable over https://stackoverflow.com/a/307154/61624 or are there scenarios the linked answer has advantages?

Comment: @DanielKaplan, honestly, embedding filenames in the shell code (the `sh -c "echo {} ..."`) is just a bad idea. I can't see it would have any upsides...

Comment: This overcounts the number of characters in each filename, because it includes the path (i.e. the "./" prefix before each filename), and also the newline added after each name. So it would list the filename "a" as being 4 bytes (actually the length of `./a<newline>`).

Answer (score 1):

Even though `-exec echo {}` avoids *shell* processing, many versions of *echo* mangle argument(s) containing backslash or leading hyphen. (And of course it doesn't pipe to `wc` as you want.)

Instead of executing `wc` for each pathname, I would use a program that is designed to handle multiple input lines aka records:

```
find . | awk '{print length}'   # basecase

# if in a multibyte locale and you want bytes not chars
# prefix the awk with LANG=C (or any other singlebyte)

# if pathname (ever) contains newline, and you have GNU find (and awk?)
find . -print0 | awk -vRS='\0' '{print length}'
```

Or `perl -nle 'print length'` which defaults to bytes, but I don't see a way to handle the `-print0` case to allow newlines.

Comment: Perl has a `-0` option for NUL-separated input.   `find . -print0 | perl -0ne 'print length, "\n"'`.  See `man perlrun`.  Perl also supports multi-byte unicode strings in case you want the character length no matter how many bytes each character might take.  Simple unicode support can be enable with the `-C` option.  e.g. `echo पशुपतिरपि तान्यहानि कृच्छ्राद् | perl -lne 'print length'` reports 86 bytes, but `echo पशुपतिरपि तान्यहानि कृच्छ्राद् | perl -C -lne 'print length'` reports 30 characters.   Unicode support can be very complicated - see also `man perlunicode`

Comment: oops, that should be `perl -0lne`, otherwise it will include the NUL byte in the length.  Alternatively, you can do calculations in the script - e.g. `find . -type f -print0 | perl -0ne 'print length($_) - 1, "\t$_\n"`

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to write this. I learned things from your answer, but as I said, the command is **not** my question. This solution is a one-off, and if I was trying to use a different command, this information probably wouldn't apply. I'm looking for something general-purpose; something that'll help me with commands in the future that I haven't even thought of yet.